# How to dynamically use static variables defined in another class in java?

Tags: java

I want to dynamically set value of static variables which are defined in another class in java.

```
Class A
{
// Variable Definitions -
public static site1_URL = "";
public static site2_URL = "";
....
... More variable defns
...
}
```

in class B, I want to dynamically set value of either site1_URL or site2_URL or some other, based on some variable in class B.

```
Class B 
{ 
.... 

if(var_x == "Site1")
    A.Site1_URL = "www.google.com";
elseif(var_x == "Site2")
    A.site2_URL = "www.google.com";
.... 

//instead of above I want to achieve -

A.<var_x>_URL = "www.google.com";
}
```

Comment: How about A.site1_URL = "StackOverflow.com";

Comment: Its like setting one variable out of many based on variable value in class B....
in other words -
switch(Var_b) {

Comment: so where exactly are you having trouble.  Show us the code.

Comment: Consider class A definition as mentioned above.
Class B
{
....
I want to achieve something like -
A.<Variable>_URL = "www.google.com";
....
}


I don;t want to use switch or if-elseif-else as there will be many more variables I need to set

Comment: you should use a Map with the key being the site name and the value being the URL.  the map will then support many URLs and you don't need to know the site names at compile time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achive it with reflection and [`Field`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html) class

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.lang.reflect.*;

class A {
    public static String site1_URL = "http://url1.com";
    public static String site2_URL = "http://url2.com";
}

class B {

    public void setUrl(String alias, String value) throws IllegalAccessException {
        Field[] fields = A.class.getDeclaredFields();
        for(Field field : fields) {
            if(field.getName().equals(alias + "_URL")) {
                field.set(field, value);
            }
        }
    }

}

class Application {  
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IllegalAccessException {
        B b = new B();
        b.setUrl("site1", "a1"); // sets value
        b.setUrl("site2", "a2"); // sets value
        b.setUrl("site3", "a3"); // does nothing

        System.out.println(A.site1_URL); // prints a1
        System.out.println(A.site2_URL); // prints a2
    }
}
```

Another way is to refactor the code and use [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

class Site {
    private String url;

    public Site(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }
}

class A {
    public static Map<String, Site> sites;

    static {
        sites = new HashMap<>();
        sites.put("site1", new Site("http://url1.com"));
        sites.put("site2", new Site("http://url2.com"));
    }

}

class B {

    public void setUrl(String alias, String value) {
        if(A.sites.containsKey(alias)) {
            A.sites.get(alias).setUrl(value);
        }
    }

}

class Application {  
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        B b = new B();
        b.setUrl("site1", "a1");
        b.setUrl("site2", "a2");
        b.setUrl("site3", "a3");

        System.out.println(A.sites.get("site1").getUrl());
        System.out.println(A.sites.get("site2").getUrl());
    }
}
```

I think the second way is preferable, reflection is slow and in this specific case does not make much sense. Also in the second case you can change aliases or iterate throw `Map`. You can easily modify `Site` class, add other fields and methods to it.

Comment: Thanks Nikolay. It worked for me. I used reflection and fields array.

Answer (score 0):

For static variables you prefix the variable with the class name like this:

```
A.site1_URL = "www.google.com";
```

Answer (score -2):

Consider class A definition as mentioned above.

```
Class B 
{ 
    .... 

    if(var_x == "Site1")
        A.Site1_URL = "www.google.com";
    elseif(var_x == "Site2")
        A.site2_URL = "www.google.com";
    .... 

    //instead of above I want to achieve -

    A.<var_x>_URL = "www.google.com";
 }
```

I don;t want to use switch or if-elseif-else as there will be many more variables I need to set.

Comment: You could use refection to dynamically look up field names

Comment: PS, why did you not edit your question rather than adding an answer?

Comment: Sorry abt that (I am using it first time)... Do you have good example to refer to?